# Change TextView color

Tags: android, textview

How do I change the R,G, B of an individual TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextViews do not have the property of brightness. Their foreground and background colors are set with ARGB values, such as: 0xff000000 for an opaque black background, and 0xffffffff, for opaque white foreground.

To increase brightness, just increase all of R,G, and B by the same amount.

To change the color of a TextView, you can use the `android:background` and `android:textColor` xml attributes.

Comment: @Meriem: Increasing r,g,b values proportionally will make the view appear brighter. Give a direct link to the app and I will look at it.